# Remove trailing comma from bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have a problem with `natbib`, more specifically with `plainnat`.
(However, it also happens with `unsrtnat`, so it doesn't have anything to do with `plainnat` specifically).

I have a trailing comma and fullstop after the title.
[image: Trailing comma and fullstop]

How do I get rid of the trailing comma?

Interestingly, when I change some things sometimes the comma disappears.
I also have another bib item with the exact same attributes for which no comma appears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{web:osm,
    title = {OpenStreetMap Wiki},
    url = {https://wiki.openstreetmap.org},
    note = {Accessed: 3rd November, 2019}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{web:osm}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Note: this small demo seems to work, that means there are other side effects which cause the comma.

Comment: Please prepear a complete [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Both `plainnat` and `unsrtnat` expect a non-empty `year` field. They also dislike empty `author` fields. You should be getting warning messages to this effect. (Are you ignoring these messages?)

Comment: Didn't get any of those messages.

Comment: @h345k34cr - Did you check the blg (“bibtex log”) file?

Comment: @Mico ok, yes, you're right. The year field is missing. What should I do if I do not want such, I mean I already have the access date separately.

Comment: @h345k34cr - Can you really not find out when the webpage was first published? If  everything else fails and if the webpage looks like it’s reasonably active, it would be ok to you the current calendar year as the publication year,